# laravel error code: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\PostController] does not exist

Tags: laravel

I've got an error in laravel named

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\PostController] does not exist

The code below is from my `PostsController`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Post;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function postCreate(Request $request)
{
   $id = Auth::id();
   $gebrnaam = Auth::name();
   $post = new Post();
   $image = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
   $post->image_path = $image;
   $request->image->move(public_path('img'), $image);
   $post->Titel = $request->input('txtTitle');
   $post->Inleiding = $request->input('txtinleiding');
   $post->Inhoud = $request->input('txtinhoud');
   $post->user_id = $id;
   $post->userNaam = $gebrnaam;
   $post->save();
}
```

And this is the code of my `web.php`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

Route::get('/', function () {

    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {

     return view('dashboard');
 })->name('dashboard');

Route::get('/', [PostController::class, 'getpost']);
Route::post('/', [PostController::class, 'postCreate']);
```

Comment: Does `PostController` exist in the `app/Http/Controllers` directory and do you have the correct spelling?

Comment: yes it does and it has the correct spelling so idk what i am doing wrong

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `PostsController != PostController`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared the **class** in your PostContoller so the Laravel is throwing an exception as it is not able to find the controller class.

```
class PostController extends Controller
 {
 //
 }
```

Wrap your code in class PostController so as follows:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Post;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 class PostController extends Controller{ 
    
    public function postCreate(Request $request)
    {
       $id = Auth::id();
       $gebrnaam = Auth::name();
       $post = new Post();
       $image = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
       $post->image_path = $image;
       $request->image->move(public_path('img'), $image);
       $post->Titel = $request->input('txtTitle');
       $post->Inleiding = $request->input('txtinleiding');
       $post->Inhoud = $request->input('txtinhoud');
       $post->user_id = $id;
       $post->userNaam = $gebrnaam;
       $post->save();
      }

    }
```

For reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#basic-controllers

Comment: sorry that was the only part i didnt copy over to stackoverflow my bad, i alreadey have it like the example from above... so that was not the mistake that i made

Comment: Is the controller file named PostController or PostController in the directory?

Comment: the 2 options you just asked are the same ...